# CSS white-space: nowrap results in overflow

Tags: css, overflow, whitespace

so I have a container with input field and its description. In case of the description being very short, I would like to have it next to the input field, but in case of longer one I don't want it to be split into two lines. I tried to solve it with white-space:nowrap; property on the description, but the problem is, that if the description is very long, it overflows the container.

Here is a simple showcase:
https://jsfiddle.net/mw2gpLqd/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" />
    <span>Very long description which wraps to new line</span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to make the description prevent from being split to two lines but still be wrapped in case it should overflow the container?

Thanks!

Comment: it's doing **exactly** what you told it to do. Just remove the `white-space:nowrap;`

Comment: can you confirm if https://jsfiddle.net/6aw8L1v5/ is correct interpretation of your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use display: inline-block property.

```
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" />
    <span style="display: inline-block;">
    Very long description which wraps to new line
    Very long description which wraps to new line
    Very long description which wraps to new line
    Very long description which wraps to new line
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, this works perfectly. I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Just update your `.description` class

```
.description {
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

you can find working sample here : https://jsfiddle.net/6aw8L1v5/

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this is not exactly what I was looking for. I wanted a behavior that @Solonka achieved.

Comment: Despite not what the OP is looking for, this is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

You should use flex

I edited your fiddle to show desired behavior - https://jsfiddle.net/defsrk9p/

or here's an example

```css
body {
  background: white;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<input type="text" />
<span>[min]</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
<input type="text" />
<span>Longer description which wraps to new line</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
<input type="text" />
<span class="description">Very long description which wraps to new line</span>
</div>

<div class="container">
<input type="text" />
<span class="description">Even longer description which will overflow the width of the container, because it has the white-space: nowrap; property</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

did you try Display block?

`.description {display:block;}`